# Javascript menu items images not sticking

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have this website

http://www.acornbusinessconsultants.co.uk/

The menu for different pages is meant to stick gray for the corresponding page - it worked fine before I converted it to Wordpress but I'm not sure that's the issue

Could someone take a look for me and tell my what im doing wrong :(

**Update:**

Heres the code im using - a friend copied it from somewhere but im not sure how it works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for that part of the menu?

Comment: The image URLs aren't changing to the active image, which I'm guessing is something PHP related behind the scenes that we can't see just from looking at the site.

Comment: I think your friend copied that JavaScript from the 1990s... they're the old Macromedia rollover scripts. Brings back memories :)  But anyway, those only handle the rollovers, not the initial rendering of the images, which is the problem here.

Comment: LOL awesome - right im going to hunt for a better menu on the net - can this been done in CSS?

Comment: Have you edited the Wordpress template files to put the menu in? If so, have a look there to see if there's any logic regarding the display of `index_` vs `undex_` images based on the current page. I'm guessing not...

Comment: Yes, it can definitely be done in CSS - that's the way to go. Depending on your template you can define the menu in Wordpress and then use CSS classes to change the background of the menu item to denote the active page.

Comment: @Town - your absolutly right! iv just looked at the original code and there is diffrent undex and index images for each page! doh! where as wordpress has only one page for all pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment conversation, it looks to me like the logic to determine the current page is missing from the Wordpress template.

You can either continue using images as you've got there, or preferably switch to using CSS to handle the rollovers/active item changes.

Either way you'll need logic to determine the current page.